# Reload model when associated records has changed

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a nested list with a few hasMany associations:

```
Customers
    Projects
        Tasks
```

Now I'm getting this data with my `loadData` method:

```
var _this = this;

// get customers with active projects
this.store.find('customer', { hasProjects: true, getArchivedProjects: false }).then(function(customers) {

  // sort customers by name
  customers = Ember.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Ember.SortableMixin, {
    sortProperties: ["name"],
    content: customers
  });

  // build array which includes customers and their projects
  var promises = customers.map(function(customer) {

    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      customer: customer,
      projects: customer.get('projects').then(function(projects) {

        // reload projects
        var project_array = [];
        projects.forEach(function(project) {
          project_array.push(project.get('id'));
        });

        projects = _this.store.findQuery('project', { ids: project_array, archived: false });

        // sort projects by name
        return Ember.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Ember.SortableMixin, {
          sortProperties: ["name"],
          content: projects
        });

      })
    });

  });

  Ember.RSVP.all(promises).then(function(filteredProjects) {
    _this.set('filteredProjectsWithoutUnassignedOnes', filteredProjects);
    _this.getUnassignedProjects(false);
  });

}
```

The problem is: when adding tasks to projects, the template doesn't update, because the project model doesn't update (see this line: `projects: customer.get('projects')`)

To update the template I wrote this dirty code:

```
// reload projects
var project_array = [];
projects.forEach(function(project) {
  project_array.push(project.get('id'));
});

projects = _this.store.findQuery('project', { ids: project_array, archived: false });
```

Is there another method to achieve that? I've read a lot about observers, but I don't get, where to place the observer in this specific case.

The goal is to update the `project` model when adding `tasks` to it.